# Pagination with flutter gridview fails

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to integrate pagination with gridview.builder,it's working in listview without any problem but in gridview it doesn't work as expected,The problem i am facing is The API data is returns 20 data per page,

**Problem**:In API it returns 20 data/page,in this API it returns total of 21 data,in 1 st page contains 20 data 2nd page contains only 1 data the pagination is working i can load data but i cannot scroll back to page 1 data it just stuck with page 2 data

I am following this [Tutorial](https://www.initpals.com/flutter/how-to-lazy-load-large-list-from-http-rest-api-with-pagination-in-flutter/),this is working with listview without no problem but in gridview the above problem occurs

**InitState and Variable initialization**

```
 var page = 1;
  ScrollController _sccontroller = new ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future token = SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    token.then((data) async {
      userToken = data;
      this.getSearchResult(page);
      _sccontroller.addListener(() {
        if (_sccontroller.position.pixels ==
            _sccontroller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          getSearchResult(page);
        }
      });
    });
    setState(() {
      title = name;
    });


  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sccontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

**Gridview**

```
GridView.builder(
          controller: _sccontroller,
          itemCount: search_result_list.length + 1,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(childAspectRatio: 5.2 / 8.0, 
          crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 3.0, mainAxisSpacing: 3.0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == search_result_list.length) {
              return Center(child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
            } else {
              return Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      // height: 700,
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 2,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            width: 300,
                            //height: 500,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        Urls.baseImageUrl +
                                            search_result_list[index]
                                                .thumb_path,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        height: 180,
                                        width: 180,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: Align(
                                          child: Text(
                                            search_result_list[index].name,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 11,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          ),
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        )),
                                  
                                  ],
                                ),
                               
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        )
```

API Function

```
 Future<void> getSearchResult(int index) async {
    print("size" + index.toString());
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      // ProgressDialog dialog = CustomDialogs().showLoadingProgressDialog(context);
      List<PrefrenceModel> tList = List();
      var response = await http.get(
        "${Urls.baseUrl}${Urls.CategorySearch}?latitude=${Constants
            .latitude}&longitude=${Constants
            .longitude}&radius=100&locale=en&keyword=${slug}&page=${index
            .toString()}&type=item",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${userToken}",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },
      );

      Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
        try {
          print("response search " + response.body.toString());
          Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);

          var status = value['success'];
          var message = value['message'];
          last_page = value['last_page'];
          print(message);
          if (status == true) {
            search_result_list.clear();
            try {
              var data = value['data']['data'];
              if (data.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  var obj = data[i];
                  //var petrol_obj = obj['petrolstation'];
                  search_result_list.add(PrefrenceModel(
                    obj['id'].toString(),
                    obj['description'].toString(),
                    obj['valid_from'].toString(),
                    obj['valid_to'].toString(),
                    obj['thumbs']['md'].toString(),
                    obj['status'].toString(),
                    "",
                    "",
                    obj['name'].toString(),
                    "",
                    obj['flyer_slug'].toString(),
                    obj['type'].toString(),
                    obj['isClipped'],
                    obj['url'].toString(),
                    obj['price'].toString(),
                    obj['flyer_page_id'].toString(),
                    obj['id'].toString(),
                    obj['shop_name'].toString(),
                    obj['shop_logo'].toString(),
                    obj['brand_name'].toString(),
                    obj['brand_logo'].toString(),
                  ));
                }
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                  search_result_list.addAll(tList);
                  page++;
                });
              } else {
                final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("No Data Available"));
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              e.toString();
            }
          } else {
            print("Error...");
            final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        var message = value['message'];
        // dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
    }
    else
      {
        setState(() { isLoading = false; });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please put getSearchResult code ?

Comment: i have updated the code,i have no problem retrieving data and show to gridview,let's say the page loads with 20 data first then i scroll to the end then it loads next page data it shows the data but the page 1 will be lost i cannot scrollback@ikerfah

Comment: Check my answer please, probably i find the issue. please check and tell me.

Comment: it was small mistake that cost 2 days@ikerfah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination will gives you the data related to the page, for example page one will returns data from 1 to 20, page two from 21 to 40. so you have to add data of page 2 to existed data from page 1. but in your case you are calling `search_result_list.clear();` this will erase the old data and put only the new data into the list.

Comment: oh man,it worked,i have't pay attention to it,i have busting my balls for this for almost 2 days,damn manh,Thanks man you saved me,i have been trying using plugins for this,thought i am done something wrong,✌✌@ikerfah

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, thanks for your beautiful words i appreciate it!